# Add Disable Button On Submit In My JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to include the JS disable button ON SUBMIT in below my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#haps').bind("blur focus keydown keypress keyup", function(){recount();});
        $('input.button').attr('disabled','disabled');

        $('#hapsForm').submit(function(e){

            haps();

        });

    });
```

This I give the function to prevent double post.
So have an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can dot this by

```
attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

like

```
 $('#hapsForm').submit(function(e){
  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            haps();

        });
```